# How can I change the Notification font color and/or background color?

Tags: themes, notifications

Elementary OS newbie here. I'm loving it so far! I've messed with the themes some what and I now have my notification background black and the text black. Makes it hard to see :(. I'm searching for the settings file to alter either the background color or the textColor.

Any insights? I've tried altering /usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css but not having any luck there. It may just be my lack of css knowledge.

Comment: Works awesome! Thanks you so much! [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/htWMO.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/htWMO.png)

Answer (score 5):

This is how I fixed it:

In Terminal, run

```
sudo nano /usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css
```

This brings up an editor. Under the `Gala` section, add:

```
.gala-notification GtkLabel {
    color: #fff;
 }
```

Save, log out and back in.

More info in [Switchboard Desktop Plug bug #1459530](https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-pantheon-shell/+bug/1459530).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to figure out, which CSS value is messed up, you could easily reinstall the elementary theme:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-theme
```

Don't forget to restart/relogin afterwards.

Comment: Tried this to no avail. I'm using the dark theme and notifications are still dark on dark. :(

Comment: @TylerHarris the dark theme is not meant to be used as main theme, that's the reason some things don't look right.