# How to change the background color of the notifications popup?

Tags: notifications, color

I have installed the Flatabulous theme and the Paper icons on my OS but unfortunately the background color of the notifications popup is transparent, which is pretty hard to read it sometimes.
How can I change the color of the popup and turn it into black or something different?

thanks in advance for the answers!

ps: I have already read [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/how-can-i-change-the-notification-font-color-and-or-background-color) but it was not useful because I don't know where is located the file that they mention in the post.
Anyways, here is an example of my notifications popup: as you can see it's hard to see, almost impossible...

[image]

Comment: most gtk themes out there break the elementary OS appearance and consistency.

Comment: does this mean that there's nothing to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

Just as the post you linked says you can open the file by entering

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css
```

in the terminal. Once it's open look for the section that starts with this

```
/*******
* Gala *
*******/
```

The default CSS code looks like this:

```
.gala-notification {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(
            to bottom,
            @bg_color,
            @bg_color 80%,
            shade (
                @bg_color,
                0.94
            )
        );
```

You need to change it to this:

```
.gala-notification {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(
            to bottom,
            @bg_color,
            @bg_color 80%,
            shade (
                @bg_color,
                0.94
            )
        );

.gala-notification GtkLabel {
    color: #fff;
 }
```

Log out then log back in.

Comment: It does not work: the popup is still transparent.

Comment: Your theme is missing GTK widget css code for GTKListBox and Content View. You would need to rebuild the theme or try the theme linked below that handles the GTK popovers correctly, then compare codes an reverse engineer. http://fav.me/dbh88n2